# How to split a string with a regex of 2 delimiters, but keep the delimiters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, split, token, csv

Say I have this string. `"+2x-10+5"`. I want to split it into `['+2x','-10','+5']`.

So, I can use regular expression to make it `['2x','10','5']`, but I want to keep the separators, which are the plus and minus signs.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you could share your code which you have come up with so far, then it would be much easier to help you out :)

Comment: There could be a few different approaches to this. Can you show what you have written so far. You could either, instead of using split, just use a regex to capture in groups like `([+-]?\w+)` with re.findall. Alternatively if you really want to use re.split you could use a positive look ahead and look behind for the split. for example ` (?<=\w)(?=[+-])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `re.split()`, use `re.findall()` with a regexp that matches each sub-expression.

```
import re

s = "+2x-10+5"
result = re.findall(r'[-+]\w+', s)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple and elegant answer!!!